# Android onTouch method on an image

Tags: android

I'm new to Android, so please excuse me if this is asked before. I have an application wherein there is an image. What I'd like to do is, when I position my finger on some part of the image, that part will be highlighted, but this is just optional for me, and when I touch that part, I would be navigated to another activity. Any ideas on how to do this? if you know some tutorials, please give me the links. Thanks. Appreciate it when you give me some ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    float xCo = event.getX();
                    float yCo = event.getY();
                    if (xCo < 100F && yCo < 100F)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, NEXT_ACTIVITY.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Of course you'll need to change my `if` statement with your real numbers.

Comment: Thanks. you said real numbers, does that mean the coordinates? What if , my application is displayed on different devices with different sizes of screen?

Comment: INSIDE the touchlistener you could get the ImageView's height/width: YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.getWidth()

Comment: Lets say that the image is divided to four quarters. You want to detect a touch in the upper left quarter:  if (xCo < YOURVIEW.getWidth() / 2 && yCo < YOURVIEW.getHeight() / 2)